# asp.net wcf service throws 404

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Im trying to implement a wcf service but am getting a 404 error. I want to have a REST service that returns JSON.

See the code I have below, however, when I go to: www.domain.nl/api or to www.domain.nl/api/getobjects I get a 404

What am I missing?

***** web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name="wcf_geolocation">
       <!-- not sure which class I should name here, see my attached code for definition of interface-->
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://www.domain.nl/api" />
           <!--  /api is the URL I want, do I need to configure that in URL rewrite or IIS or...?-->
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint address="getobjects" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Iwcf_geolocation" />
     </service>
   </services>

   <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
```

***** Iwcf_geolocation.vb

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Text
' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface name "Iwcf_geolocation" in both code and config file together.
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface Iwcf_geolocation

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub DoWork()


    <OperationContract()> _
<WebGet()> _
    Function EchoWithGet(ByVal s As String) As String

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke()> _
    Function EchoWithPost(ByVal s As String) As String


End Interface
```

***** wcf_geolocation.vb

```
' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the class name "wcf_geolocation" in code, svc and config file together.
Public Class wcf_geolocation
    Implements Iwcf_geolocation

    Public Sub DoWork() Implements Iwcf_geolocation.DoWork
    End Sub

    Public Function EchoWithGet(ByVal s As String) As String Implements Iwcf_geolocation.EchoWithGet
        Return "You said " + s
    End Function

    Public Function EchoWithPost(ByVal s As String) As String Implements Iwcf_geolocation.EchoWithPost
        Return "You said " + s
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: @geek, it was there, just not formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like that problem is in the Binding for REST binding should be [webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx).I have made some modifications in your web.config.try this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="wcf_geolocation" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- not sure which class I should name here, see my attached code for definition of interface-->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://www.domain.nl/api" />
            <!--  /api is the URL I want, do I need to configure that in URL rewrite or IIS or...?-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="getobjects"  behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Iwcf_geolocation" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT**

Hi I have updated the answer as per your comment.Please have a look and let me know.

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Text
' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface name "Iwcf_geolocation" in both code and config file together.
<ServiceContract> _
Public Interface Iwcf_geolocation


    <OperationContract> _
    Sub DoWork()

    <OperationContract> _
    <WebGet(RequestFormat := WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat := WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate := "EchoWithGet/{s}")> _
    Function EchoWithGet(s As String) As String

    <OperationContract> _
    <WebInvoke(Method := "POST", UriTemplate := "EchoWithPost/{s}", BodyStyle := WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)> _
    Function EchoWithPost(s As String) As String


End Interface





Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the class name "wcf_geolocation" in code, svc and config file together.
Public Class wcf_geolocation
    Inherits Iwcf_geolocation

    Public Sub DoWork()
    End Sub
    Public Function EchoWithGet(s As String) As String
        Return "You said " & s
    End Function

    Public Function EchoWithPost(s As String) As String
        Return "You said " & s
    End Function

End Class
```

---

```
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**How to test the service in browser**

http://[XXXX.XXX]/ServiceName.svc/EchoWithGet/peter

for **EchoWithPost** service you have to write code or you can test this with fiddler.

Comment: Ok cool. I replaced my code with your code in my web.config. I however still get the 404 when I go to: http://www.domain.nl/api/getobjects or to http://www.domain.nl/api...anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I tried your code on local machine and everything is fine.call the reset method like Service.svc/EchoWithGet/s

Comment: replace getobjects string with empty in web.config and then try the above address

Comment: I think it works: when I call http://www.domain.nl/wcf_geolocation.svc/EchoWithGet I get an XML response...but I need JSON...how can I do that?

Comment: Oh, and also, how would I pass a parameter to this service? E.g. username=peter?

Comment: btw: I asked the last question because when I request: /wcf_geolocation.svc/EchoWithGet/s I get: "Endpoint not found"

Comment: @geek, thx for your reply. no it hasnt been solved yet, basically what Im still struggling with is: 1) I need a JSON response instead of XML 2)how can I pass parameters, such as username=peter to this service? because when I try your code 'Service.svc/EchoWithGet/s' I get an error: Endpoint not found. thanks!

Comment: @Peter:Send me your some address so that I can send you demo app

Comment: @Peter:try your local server address...I mean localhost:port/Service.svc/EchoWithGet/s

Comment: @geek: I want to send you my emailaddress (thanks for the effort beforehand btw) but I cant seem to find your contact details on stackoverflow or the option to send you a private message...

Comment: @Peter:There is no such option in stackoverflow ...send me on this email address santi.noida@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Run Server Manager (on task bar and start menu)
Choose the server to administer (probably local server)
Scroll down to "Roles and Features" section.
Choose "Add Role or Feature" from Tasks drop down
On "Add Role or Feature Wizard" dialog, click down to "Features" in list of pages on the left.
Expand ".Net 3.5" or ".Net 4.5", depending on what you have installed. (you can go back up to "roles" screen to add if you don't have.
Under "WCF Services", check the box for "HTTP-Activation". You can also add non-http types if you know you need them (tcp, named pipes, etc).
Click "Install" Button.